# Search people in Twitter in Java (Twitter4j)

Tags: search, twitter, twitter4j

Does anyone know a way to use Twitter4j or any other lib in order to search people in Twitter through its API? I am trying to find out if specific people have Twitter accounts.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#searchUsers%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) should answer your question. [This](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) should help you build a basic query

Answer (score 0):

This is the API for searching users in twitter:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=UserName
```